# PHP maths rounds values

Tags: php, mysql, database, math

In my database I have many columns of type: `VARCHAR`
Some of them contains numbers like lets say: `12,25`. And now I have a situation when I have to SUM these columns. Lets say it looks like that:

```
[-COL1--COL2--COL3-]
[-12,5--0,00--0,00-]
```

So the SUM of COL1+COL2+COL3 should be 12.5, but it gives me 12 only. If I print each column seperate without summing it it shows good value. Whats the problem?

Comment: Why do you have numbers that you want to do arithmetic with in a `VARCHAR` column?

Comment: commas are decimals?

Comment: Your country may use comma as a decimal seperator, but mathmatic functions dont. **Or are they supposed to be 2 integers with a comma seperator**

Comment: Show the code you use to add the columns.

Comment: 1. See normalisation

Comment: That's right. I forgot that for maths you cannot use comma. Thanks guys for help.

Comment: How did these numbers get comma-decimal-seperated in your database in the first place? If by PHP check your localization settings. http://php.net/set_locale. If you use an Locale with comma-decimal values as LC_NUMERIC or LC_ALL floats will convert to strings with comma's.

Comment: My customer gave me data in this kind of format. I don't even check just imported it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have 12,5 instead of 12.5
Try to change it with this:

```
$number = '12,5';
$number = str_replace(',', '.', $number);
```

and then add it up

Comment: This is PHP, the `sum` is at the db level.

Comment: the post's title is PHP maths

Comment: Guess have to wait and see what OP is actually doing when the code is provided.

Comment: Thank you. The problem really was the comma. I just replaced all `,` to `.` in my database and now everything is ok.